# UDP Multicast data not being received by clients

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, multicast, udpclient

Here's my code... I've tried many things, but none of them work. I'm sure there's something I'm missing. The intent is that a client listens to the given _remoteEndpoint address. Instead, nothing is found at all, despite showing the broadcast in Wireshark, windump, etc. The ports are open, firewall disabled and so on. I tried our legacy code 1:1 and it also didn't work, but it works in the old binaries without issue. Did something change from .NET 4 to .NET 6 with how this functions?

This is on Windows of various versions.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using Easy.Logger.Interfaces;
using Easy.Logger;
using MktSrvcAPI.Sockets;
using RBClients.SprdClient;

namespace SpreadFeedPubSub.DAL
{
    public class MulticastEndpoint
    {
        private static readonly IEasyLogger log = Log4NetService.Instance.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public int AssociatedFilterId { get; private set; }
        public string AssociatedFilterName { get; private set; }
        public IPAddress Address { get; private set; }
        public int Port { get; private set; }
        private IPEndPoint _remoteEndpoint;
        public Socket MulticastClient { get; private set; }
        public ByteBuffer Buffer { get; private set; }
        public string Protocol { get; private set; }

        private int _maxBufferSize;

        public MulticastEndpoint(string ip, int port, int associatedFilter = -1, int bufferSize = 2048)
        {
            Address = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            Port = port;
            _remoteEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(Address, Port);
            _maxBufferSize = Math.Min(bufferSize, 2048);
            Buffer = new ByteBuffer(_maxBufferSize);
            AssociatedFilterId = associatedFilter;
        }

        public void SendData(Message data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            lock (Buffer)
            {
                if (Buffer.UnusedLength < data.Length)
                {
                    SendBuffer();
                }
                Buffer.Append(data.Bytes, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

        public void SendBuffer()
        {
            if (Buffer.SIZE == Buffer.UnusedLength)
            {
                return;
            }
            MulticastClient.SendTo(Buffer.DATA, _remoteEndpoint);
            Buffer.Clear();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            try
            {
                MulticastClient.Close();
                MulticastClient.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log.Error($"StartConnection {IP}:{Port} - " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Create()
        {
            try
            {
                MulticastClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                MulticastClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                MulticastClient.EnableBroadcast = true;
                MulticastClient.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(Address, Program.IFACE_HOST));
                MulticastClient.Bind(new IPEndPoint(Program.IFACE_HOST, Port));
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                //log.Error($"StartConnection {IP}:{Port} - " + se.ToString());
                if (se.ErrorCode == 10048)
                {
                    log.Error("Socket already being used.");
                }
                throw (se);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log.Error($"StartConnection {IP}:{Port} - " + ex.ToString());
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried

- UdpClient with JoinMulticast, exclusiveaddress false, broadcast true, Send to _remoteEndpoint.
- Socket with and without options, with and without exclusiveaddress, broadcast, with and without Bind.

Comment: You haven't shown how you are using it, but your existing code waits until it has a full buffer to send the data. `UdpClient` is the right way to go, but we can't see how you've written that either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was TTL. Setting the TimeToLive to 15 fixed it.
`MulticastClient.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 15);`